# Why python3 dict's get method O(1) time while under the hood it is aclually O(n)?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

We all know that python `dict.get()` has `O(1)` time complexity because it need to get a hash of the key and get value, corresponding to it's key. The question is, what magic can actually access the value, corresponding to the hash? Looking for the answer I went to [do_lookup](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c#L1010) method in CPython and found out the interpreter iterates over all buckets to find the needed hash.

```
do_lookup(PyDictObject *mp, PyDictKeysObject *dk, PyObject *key, Py_hash_t hash,
          Py_ssize_t (*check_lookup)(PyDictObject *, PyDictKeysObject *, void *, Py_ssize_t ix, PyObject *key, Py_hash_t))
{
    // ...
    for (;;) {
        ix = dictkeys_get_index(dk, i);
        if (ix >= 0) {
            Py_ssize_t cmp = check_lookup(mp, dk, ep0, ix, key, hash);
            if (cmp < 0) {
                return cmp;
            } else if (cmp) {
                return ix;
            }
        }
        else if (ix == DKIX_EMPTY) {
            return DKIX_EMPTY;
        }
        perturb >>= PERTURB_SHIFT;
        i = mask & (i*5 + perturb + 1);
        // ...
    }
}
```

so due to this and also keep in mind hash collision resolver it looks like this:

```
O(1) only if first hash + no collision - best case
O(N) for worst case + no collision 
O(N) + O(len(bucket)) for worst case + collision resolver
```

am I missing something or what is wrong with this logic?

Comment: It's known that dict lookup costs *O(n)* in time complexity in worst case scenarios, and *O(1)* time *on average*. What makes you think you're more likely to encounter the worse case scenarios than not?

Comment: @blhsing More clearly the question is, why the average case of lookup is O(1)? What causes the needed hash to be met first/second/etc while iterating over them? I see it is best case O(1) - needed hash met first, avg. case is O(buckets_amount / 2) and worst case is O(n) (if there is no collisions included), how come it is O(1) avg?